# Get Class Name from Object inside Object

Tags: php, object

I have 3 classes..

class 1 :

```
<?php
include "two.php";
include "three.php";
class One{
    public function __construct(){
        $two = new Two($this);
        $three = new Three($two);
    }
}
$api = new One;
?>
```

class 2 :

```
<?php
class Two extends AOP {
    public function __construct($obj){
        //blablabla
    }
}
?>
```

class 3 :

```
<?php
class Three extends AOP {
    public function __construct($obj){
        echo get_class($obj);
    }
}
?>
```

But I want the result must output "One".
How to get class name from object inside object?

Comment: If you need this, then there's something wrong with your design

Comment: It should be: `$three = new Three($this);`

Comment: why don't you use inheritance ?

Comment: @all : thanks for answering.. but it's already answered by Mamuz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your design you have to implement a getter in class two:

class 2 :

```
class Two 
{
    private $myObj;

    public function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->myObj = $obj;
    }

    public function getMyObj()
    {
        return $this->myObj;
    }
}
```

then in class 3, you can retrieve class 1:

```
class Three 
{
    public function __construct($obj)
    {
        echo get_class($obj->getMyObj());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `extends` to inherit another class. Since PHP does not support multiple inheritances directly. You can get the class that you extend from with `parent::$property;` or `parent::method();`. So, you probably want your code to look more like.

```
// three.php
class Three extends AOP{
  public function __construct($obj){
    echo get_class($obj);
  }
}

// two.php
class Two extends Three{
  public function __construct($obj){
    parent::__construct($obj); // Constructors do not return a value echo works
  }
  protected function whatever($string){
    return $string;
  }
}

// one.php
include 'three.php'; // must be included first for Two to extend from
include 'two.php'
class One extends Two{
  public function __construct(){
    // change this part
    parent::__construct($this); // uses the parent Constructor
    echo $this->whatever('. Is this what you mean?'); // call method without same name in this class - from parent
  }
}
$api = new One;
```

I would not use your structure at all, but this should give you an idea of inheritance.

Comment: sorry for misstype my code.. class two and three already extends class AOP so I can't extends more than 1.. but thanks for answering PHPglue :D